# Tampermonkey: Hashtag in @match URL

Tags: javascript, match, tampermonkey

I have this link that i want to run a userscript on:
`https://someurl.somewhere.com/#/some/create-on`

and
`@match https://someurl.somewhere.com/#/some/create-on`
doesn't work.

I figured it might be the hashtag but I don't really know.. I thought of this as a solution but it doesn't work:
`@match https://someurl.somewhere.com/*/some/create-on`

I need help. Userscript is in tampermonkey ofc.

Answer (score 0):

`#` in URL is regarded as [Location: hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash), therefore in your example:

- main URL: `https://someurl.somewhere.com/`
- location hash: `#/some/create-on`

Userscripts should match the main URL e.g.

```
@match       https://someurl.somewhere.com/
```

or if there would be an unknown [Location: pathname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/pathname) ...

```
@match       https://someurl.somewhere.com/*
```